# MS Outlook cannot log in to GMail anymore

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

Google announced a while ago that security would be strengthened as of May 30. Indeed, since today, I cannot log anymore into my GMail pop account using Outlook 2019. This was working fine since ages, and I didn't touch the connection parameters. (I have activated two-step connection on my Google account today, to no avail.)

What can I do ?

Comment: You can start by checking https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-more-secure-apps%2Cuse-an-app-password

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: yep, thanks. I just found a solution, which is to use an App Password.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook can be re-enabled by means of an "App Password". The procedure is described here:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There IS documentation in my answer.